# Get data based on Months (Name) excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, date

Im currently creating a template for our report. And I would like to do some automation.

I have a source sheet which I call "KPISource" (Data source is in sharepoint, thus this is a table). And in the first column I would like to get data which has has the current Month and the previous month.

Basically, If it is current month, it will then put the data in the "August" column. And If the date is previous month, then it will also put the data in the "July".

[image: Below is the screenshot of our template:]

In my source sheet, the columns are Date, Tickets Solved (productivity), YTD, Ticket Reopen Rate(quality), Aging <5 days (Quality), YTD (Aging <5 days) Aging > 5 days (Quality), YTD (Aging >5 days), Customer Satisfaction, YTD (Customer Satisfaction)

Currently here is my code, but no output is appearing. This is the code that I'm trying if the there is a previous date in column 1 (KPISource), then it will have the value in KPI.Cells(6, 4).Value (Tickets Solved "July").

```
Sub OperationalKPI()

Dim KPI As Worksheet
Set KPI = Sheets("OperationalKPI")
Dim KPISource As Worksheet
Set KPISource = Sheets("KPISource")


mPrevious = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm")
mCurrent = Format(Date, "mmmm")


lastrow = KPISource.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To lastrow

If mPrevious = KPISource.Cells(x, 1) Then

   KPI.Cells(6, 4).Value = KPISource.Cells(x, 2).Value

End If

Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: You are only putting information into ONE cell, cell referenced (6,4), is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, as I need to put the Tickets Solved (column 2) data into the (6,4) which is the tickets solved -> July.

Comment: Look at the dates column in the source spreadsheet. Are they stored as text with the month name or as full dates with  a formatting on the cells?

Comment: I checked the dates column and it is formatted as Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, based upon your feedback, is in the line

```
If mPrevious = KPISource.Cells(x, 1) Then
```

mPrevious is a string containing the name of the month, eg "July", however KPISource.Cells(x, 1) contains a date so the two are never going to be equal.

Change the line to:

```
If mPrevious = Format(KPISource.Cells(x, 1),"mmmm") Then
```

This will make both items strings with the name of the month in them and the If should find the matches.

Comment: Hi Rob, I would just like to ask another question. I tried to add a date in the date column which is 07/01/2018. In this case, they are the same month. Thus it gets the value of 07/01/2018 which is the last row. What I would like to get is the current month of the current year so this tool can be used for next year. Could you please advise what could be the solution? Thank you.

Comment: I think I just have to add "yyyy" in mPrevious = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm yyyy")
mCurrent = Format(Date, "mmmm yyyy") and If mPrevious = Format(KPISource.Cells(x, 1),"mmmm yyyy")

Comment: I have tried to add couple of dates which are 2018 and it worked. Thank you!